# Is it true that $R.L^* + L^* = R + L^*$?

Tags: regular-languages, regular-expressions

I am trying to solve a problem to show equivalence between two regular expressions, and simplifying one of them I got $R.L^* + L^*$ in the end which I am not sure how to simplify further.

I want to equate it to $R + L^*$. Is this equivalence correct or is there a way to derive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's false in general. Pick $R = a$ and $L=b$. The word $ab$ is in the language defined by $RL^* + L$ but not in the language of $R+L^*$.

It might be true for your specific choice of $R$ and $L$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes it clear!